# Playframework [Scala]: Binding a list/seq to the controller

Tags: html, scala, list, playframework

I am trying to bind a list of input items on my html page to my controller.

My form is defined as:

```
def clientForm = Form( tuple(
       "clients[]" -> seq( tuple(
          "firstname" -> text,
          "lastname" -> text) )
    ) )
```

In my HTML I have tried the following:

```
@b3.text(thisForm("clients[0]"), '_label -> "first client", 'value -> "('John','Snow')")
@b3.text(thisForm("clients[1]"), '_label -> "second client", 'value -> "('Frank','Carson')")
```

I have also tried:

```
@b3.text(thisForm("clients[0].firstname"), '_label -> "first client fistname", 'value -> "John")
@b3.text(thisForm("clients[0].lastname"), '_label -> "first client lastname", 'value -> "Snow")
@b3.text(thisForm("clients[1].firstname"), '_label -> "second client fistname", 'value -> "Frank")
@b3.text(thisForm("clients[2].lastname"), '_label -> "second client lastname", 'value -> "Carson")
```

In debug mode upon POST I can see that these values get bound to the form within the controller:

```
val boundFrom = inForm.bindFromRequest
```

But when I `boundForm.fold` mapping to `clientForm` the values to not map correctly to my `"clients[]"` element.

I'm at a loss and have spent ages looking for the answer to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**
Here's a screenshot in debug mode.  The values are being bound to the form but then do not get assigned.
[Debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykEIy.png)

Comment: What's the error you are getting in `.fold` error block?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in my fold block

Comment: Why your `clientForm` is `tuple` if it has only `clients[]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your form definition can be as following -

```
def clientForm = Form( 
    single(
        "clients[]" -> seq(
            tuple(
                "firstname" -> text,
                "lastname" -> text
            ) 
        )
    ) 
)
```

Then you second way of writing template is correct as you can see in documentation here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#Repeated-values

Now what you will get when you fold this form is that a seq of tuples and you can use it like following -

```
clientForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    error => // Handle error
    clients => {// this clients is of signature Seq[(String, String)]
        clients.map{client => logger.log("First name: " + client._1 + ", Last name: " + client_2)}
    }
)
```

Please note that you have to use tuple ._1 and ._2 to access your first name and last name here. As you are getting a tuple (String, String) not a Map[String, String] here.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tarun.  I had simplified my form somewhat for my question but clients[] is actually one of many fields in a tuple.  I still get the same problem though.  When I bind the form and look in debugger mode I can see clientForm.data[0] = clients[0].firstname and then clientForm.data[4] = clients[0].lastname.  I expect once folded that this random indexing of data (simply assume I have 4 elements in my tuple one element being the seq) is tidied up and populates my variable correctly.  Alas it does not.

Comment: `clientForm.data` shows the values I require in my bound form but `clientForm.value` simply has Some(List())

Comment: can you tell me exact form and what do you get in variables in fold method?

Comment: I stripped everything out and used your form (using single) and got the screenshot that you see in my edited post.  Maybe it's because I'm using IntelliJ Community or SBT.  I don't know.  For now I've just rewritten my form to avoid using seq

Comment: Please don't bother about clienForm.data or client.value it is internal representation of data and is in intermediate state (process is binding may not yet be complete in screenshot). use fold method and in that method only do further work with your validated form data. I am sure you might be getting exact same value in "clients" variable in fold method as shown in answer above. I had also added a log message that logs all values submitted in form to illustrate how you can use values from "clients" variable